# Laravel - How to get POST parameters from previous GET request

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am a beginner using Laravel but I can't wrap my head around this problem. I have a form where you retrieve the user information to pre-fill some fields. To retrieve this information I am using a GET request from the user table. When the user is going to submit the form in the POST request one of the fields is the 'user_id', but I don't know how to retrieve this information from the previous GET request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add hidden input fields in your form and you can set values which you are getting from GET request. These values will pass in POST when you submit your form.

Answer (score 0):

You should not pass user ID through a form or as a GET parameter, use `auth()->user()` to get authenticated user.

Or you could use `auth()->id()` to get authenticated user's ID.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#retrieving-the-authenticated-user